# DataBinding Error: Drop Down List and Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm getting error :

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'system_name'.

I've a drop down list which fetches data from **SYSTEMS** table. Code:

```
string queryStringForSystem = "SELECT system_name FROM ptdd.systems where system_id=(select system_id from ptdd.parameters where parameter_id='" + txtParameterId.Text + "')";
string odbccon = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};database=dd_unify;hostname=x.x.x.x;protocol=TCPIP;port=50000;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx";            
using (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(odbccon))
                {
                    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(queryStringForSrdRefId, odbccon);
                    System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                    try
                    {
                        odbcConnection.Open();
                        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                        ddrSystem.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
                        ddrSystem.DataTextField = "system_name";
                        ddrSystem.DataValueField = "system_id";
                        ddrSystem.DataBind();

                    }

                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
                }
```

Also, i've mentioned the datatextfield and datavalue field.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddrSystem" runat="server" DataTextField="system_name" DataValueField="system_id">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Though, its a minor issue. Can't able to solve it.

Comment: On `databind` it may may throwing an exception as you're not selecting `system_id` in the select list, therefore your `ddrSystem.DataValueField` will be invalid.

Comment: This means that the dataset you tried to bind with your dropdown does not have any column with name 'system_name'. You need to make sure that the field exists in the query result(based on your condition) that you used to bind with the dropdown.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt when i was selecting system_name as ValueField, it was throwing the same Exception

Comment: @Srinivas i've verified that earlier. Column name matches with the one in query and data text/value fields

Comment: Try replacing ddrSystem.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0] to ddrSystem.DataSource = dataSet

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query from

> SELECT system_name FROM...

to

> SELECT system_id, system_name FROM...

Reason: your code is looking for system_id but that field is not in the query.

> ddrSystem.DataTextField = "system_name";
>
> ddrSystem.DataValueField = "**system_id**";